# Ways to Encrypt and Decrypt pdf files android

Tags: java, android, encryption

Hello i am searching free api or some easy code to encrypt and decrypt pdf files. Encryption should be done on downloading file from a stream:

```
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                /*
                 * Writes bufferLength characters starting at 0 in buffer to the target
                 * 
                 * buffer the non-null character array to write. 0 the index
                 * of the first character in buffer to write. bufferLength the maximum
                 * number of characters to write.
                 */
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);


            }
```

And decrypt when need to open with pdf reader. Maybe there are some info, code or free Api for this ?
Someone had done something like this ?

I found myself some code and api. But nothing good for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using CipherOuputStream and CipherInputStream:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
```

Encryption:

```
public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

        // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Decryption:

```
public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this approach. Now i am thinking maybe it is wrong to encrypt pdf file as when i need to open eith pdf reader i need to decrypt and then files is unsecured. Maybe i should encrypt file structure in internal storage ?

Comment: you con encrypt streams so try to get stream from PDF and do the encryption

Comment: Yes i am trying now to encrypt stream, but my app pdf reader need file .pdf. So if i write from stream to file the decrypt file would be reachable for rooted device user ?

Comment: Maybe you know what need to be done that rooted devices users couldn't in any way to take decrypted files ?

Comment: This leads to security now, if it all a hacker happens to get that file, he still can read it because it is decrypted.But in order to prevent from others reading the decrypted file, you can password protect the .pdf file.

Comment: @UVM I don't understand! where is keys?! public and private keys.